# HTMLAgilityPack Select Nodes between Comments

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, comments

I am replacing some head script that pertains to a specific widget. I want to be able to find all nodes relating to that widget located between the comments. Also, I want to easily remove any code related to the specified widget (including the start and end comment.

The insert and removed code will look like this:

```
<!-- WidgetScript_WidgetName -->

  <script src="Widgets/jquery.somecode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">   
    $(function () {
        $('.someid).dothis({parameter, avatar_size: 48, count: 6});
      });
    </script>
    <link href="Widgets/jquery.somecode.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 

<!--WidgetScript_WidgetName End-->
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
var startNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//comment()[contains(., 'WidgetScript_WidgetName')]");
var endNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//comment()[contains(., 'WidgetScript_WidgetName End')]");
int startNodeIndex = startNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.IndexOf(startNode);
int endNodeIndex = endNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.IndexOf(endNode);

var nodes = startNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Where((n, index) => index >= startNodeIndex && index <= endNodeIndex).Select(n => n);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like this:

```
        var head = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/head");

        var nodes = new List<HtmlNode>();

        bool isComment = false;
        foreach (var node in head.ChildNodes.ToList())
        {
            if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment &&
                node.InnerText.Contains("WidgetScript_WidgetName"))
            {
                isComment = !isComment;
                node.Remove();
            }
            else if (isComment)
            {
                nodes.Add(node);
                node.Remove();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(head.InnerHtml);
```

This removes every node between two comments (and the comments themselves).

Comment: I actually did a combination of this and @jdavies to find and remove the elements.